# Differential information load of frequency ranges

Tags: phonetics

Are there any studies trying to quantify the amount of information carried by different frequency ranges in speech in different languages?

Comment: what do you mean by frequence ranges? Frequency of what phenomenon? What is the phenomenon in which the time period between each event/phase is important/measured/measurable. I cannot make my mind with the idea of a range having a frequency.

Comment: @StephaneRolland I'm fairly sure the OP is talking about frequencies in a spectrogram.

Comment: @WavesWashSands the frequency of the voice sound, that makes it instantly clearer for me :-)

Comment: @OP: I can't find any research that discusses information load of frequency ranges, but there is a fair amount of literature on information-theoretic measurement of functional loads of phonemes. It shouldn't be too hard to apply it to your question; if we consider the random variables in question to be the amplitude at each frequency band, then we can calculate the entropy of the language with and without that frequency band, and apply the functional load formula. If nobody has an actual answer to this question, I could elaborate on this in an answer later.

Comment: @WavesWashSands, I would be grateful for any refs to studies not focusing on English. However, there is an issue with the phoneme-based approach: a given phoneme may be highly informative as a unit, but if it is a consonant listeners will be mostly recognising it based on formant transitions, which lie in the spectral range of surrounding vowels. This will likely shift the information peak down, except for consonant-to-consonant transitions, and I would like to know if someone tried to control for this.